# callback reference and inheritance javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, inheritance, for-loop

I have two pieces of data in a multi-level array (object?) that I'm referencing in a callback function set with 2 for loops. However, I can't figure out how to get the current loop value into the callback: it uses the last value for all callbacks.

```
for (k in myobj.myarr) {
    for (m in myobj.myarr[k]){
        document.addEventListener(
            k,
            function(event){
                myobj.myfn(event, myobj['myarr'][k][m][0], myobj['myarr'][k][m][1]);
            },
            true
        );
    }
}
```

Where `myobj['myarr'][k][m][0]` are strings and `myobj['myarr'][k][m][1]` are functions. I have a `console.log` in the functions, and the same function is always called (the last one).

Yes, this is probably an odd implementation, and no, I can't use libraries. How do I get the correct values out of my array to pass into the callback functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really want is m bound to a context known only to one listener. For clarity's sake, you could define a function like this:

```
function doEvent(k, myobj, m) {
  document.addEventListener(
    k,
    function(event){
      myobj.myfn(event, myobj['myarr'][k][m][0], myobj['myarr'][k][m][1]);
    },
    true
  );
}
```

...and call it for each object in your array:

```
for (k in myobj.myarr) {
  for (m in myobj.myarr[k]){
      doEvent(k, myobj, m);  
  }
}
```

Now, the events will be specific to their respective `m`s in the loop.

Comment: I should have thought of this 20 minutes ago. DOH! Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like Javascript! :^)

Answer (score 1):

You can "lock" the value of the iterator like so:

```
for( k in myobj.myarr) {
    for( m in myobj.myarr[k]) {
        (function(m,k) {
            // code that depends on m and k here
        })(m,k);
    }
}
```

I have to ask, though, you seem to be creating a very large number of event listeners, which is bad for performance. Is there no way you could delegate the event handlers to a parent element and use `event.target` to find the actual element?

Comment: I'm attaching all events to the document, and checking the target against the string (`myobj['myarr'][k][m][0]` and executing the matching callback function. Originally, I was attempting to have one event listener per event type, then look through an array for a matching selector. It worked, but the thought here was that several event listeners on the document would be faster than one that checks an array every time. Also, the scope is highly limited on the event listeners. I'm just exploring alternate "live" functions for a project that can't use 3rd party libraries.

Comment: I wish I could vote your answer up more than once, it's VERY useful knowledge! However, I'm going to go with rjz answer for this instance. Thanks!